# Issue with UIPickerView fixed label for each component on iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I want to display a `UIPickerView` with some text hardcoded for each component. Something like "Hours" and "Mins". Now, I could achieve this by creating and putting the labels as subviews to picker view. This works fine for iOS 7 & above.

But for iOS 6, my labels are overlapped by `UIPickerView` components so they are not visible. How could I achieve this view for iOS 6 where for each component, values are tagged to a fixed label so user know what they are selecting.

Comment: Curious why you are attempting to support iOS 6 at this point in time. It's so outdated at this point. And it has a completely different look and feel than iOS 7+.

Comment: My client is still using iOS 6 so I have to support.

Comment: Just put the labels above the picker view.

Comment: I tried that put picker components comes above those labels. I guess I have to tell picker to insert labels on top of its sub views.

Comment: No, put the labels above the picker (smaller y value), not in front of the picker.

Comment: I'm setting this picker as inputView of a `UITextField` and displaying it on tap on a `UITableViewCell`. Are you saying I should simply position these labels and add as subview to my table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of others, this is how I achieved this (based on Frog's suggestion):

```
- (void)setDatePickerView:(MyCustomCell *)iCell {
    UIView *inputView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    // Add Picker First
    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.tag = 100;

    int height = 30;
    int offsetY = pickerView.frame.size.height / 2 - height / 2;

    // Add a line on top of selection
    if ([Utilities isIOS7orAbove]) {
        UIImageView *topLineView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, offsetY - 2, pickerView.frame.size.width, 1)];
        [topLineView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [pickerView addSubview:topLineView];
    }

    [inputView addSubview:pickerView];

    // Add Minute Label
    CGFloat minLabelX = [Utilities isIOS7orAbove] ? 97 : 90;
    CGFloat labelYM = [Utilities isIOS7orAbove] ? 0.0 : 1.0;
    CGFloat labelW = 50;

    UILabel *minutesLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(minLabelX, offsetY - labelYM, labelW, height)];
    minutesLabel.text = @“Mins";
    minutesLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kFontSize22];
    minutesLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    minutesLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [inputView addSubview:minutesLabel];

    // Now Add Seconds Label
    CGFloat secLabelX = [Utilities isIOS7orAbove] ? 230 : 218;
    UILabel *secondsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(secLabelX, offsetY - labelYM, labelW, height)];
    secondsLabel.text = @“Secs";
    secondsLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kFontSize22];
    secondsLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    secondsLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [inputView addSubview:secondsLabel];

    iCell.inputField.inputView = inputView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i think you can achieve this by construct a custom view which contains the picker view and the labels.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a solution. Let me try that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [ActionSheetPicker3.0](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0), I use it all the time when I need a custom picker. It works perfectly with iOS6+.

This is how you use it for String picker:

```
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hours", @"Mins", @"Whatever", @"More", nil];

[ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Select a Color"
                                        rows:colors
                            initialSelection:0
                                   doneBlock:^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker, NSInteger selectedIndex, id selectedValue) {
                                      NSLog(@"Picker: %@, Index: %@, value: %@", 
                                      picker, selectedIndex, selectedValue);
                                    }
                                 cancelBlock:^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker) {
                                      NSLog(@"Block Picker Canceled");
                                    }
                                      origin:sender];
```

Enjoy!